# GetWindowRect returns 0 after compiling but not during debug session

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT Rect);
```

--  (Further in the code)

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ExternalRunningProgram");
RECT Rect = new RECT();
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
    GetWindowRect(handle, out Rect);
}
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", Rect.Left, Rect.Right, Rect.Top, Rect.Bottom));
```

--

During debugging sessions, the above code will return the correct window size of ExternalRunningProgam. However, when running without the debugging session the `GetWindowRect()` call will always return 0's for Top/Bottom/Left/Right under normal and admin rights.

I've tried various "versions" of the `DllImport` lines to no avail and am at a loss of what could be causing it to only work during the debug session.

Comment: Are you sure the `processes` loop executed at least once without debugging. The problem may be in the process name. What is the actual process name you're trying to get window RECT from? What is the actual value of the `"ExternalRunningProgram"` literal?

Comment: it is very important to take care of error checking yourself when you pinvoke C functions so you can find out why they fail.  So this must look like `If (!GetWindowRect(handle, out rect)) throw new Win32Exception()`.  Now you know.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov "Dishonored", it's a game running in windowed mode and im trying to get my application to automatically overlay which works fine in VS. The loop does run as confirmed by a messagebox but p.MainWindowHandle returns 0, while p.Handle returns an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was actually not related to anything above, but rather due to COMODO Auto-Containment (sandbox)

Comment: Oh, well, I just looked more carefully at your code and saw that you are actually calling it on *other* applications' processes. That's probably not a bug, then. You aren't supposed to be manipulating other processes. That's the whole point of a sandbox security model. So no, you shouldn't report it after all. You should change the design of your application so you don't have to go mucking about with others.